# Power in AC circuits

Tags: power, ac

When I look at the graph of the power in AC circuits versus time (not the average power I am talking about the instantaneous power) it goes from a negative value to positive. On the other hand, I know that a positive value of p(t) represents dissipation and negative power represents generation. How could I link this concept to a sinusoidal form of power? For example, for a resistor that is connected to AC voltage source, the positive power describes the heat that is dissipated, what would negative power in negative cycle represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an AC waveform is connected to a pure resistance, the delivered power never goes negative. The current is always in phase with the voltage. When the voltage is +ve, so is the current. When the voltage is -ve, so is the current. In both cases, the power, the product of voltage and current, is +ve. While the power varies from large to zero, it never goes -ve.

If the load has an inductive or capacitive component, then the current waveform will lag or lead (respectively) the voltage waveform, and at some points in the cycle they will have different signs. When the signs are the same, the component is storing energy, and the generator is delivering positive power. When they are different, the component is returning energy to the generator, which could be mathematically consistently described as negative power.

The power due to this storage of energy is called reactive power, usually written VAr.

Comment: So dissipation for resistor would be in form of conserving energy for inductors and capacitors?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'in form of'. Energy is dissipated in a resistor, there is no storage mechanism in that component. Energy is stored in capacitors and inductors. A perfect L or C does not dissipate energy. However as they are made from real metals with resistance, they do have losses that dissipate energy, often described as effective or equivalent resistance. The voltage and the current that come from the generator are the same 'stuff', whether the load is resistive or reactive.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a picture I did for another answer - it shows how the power waveform looks for varying degrees of power factor: -

[image]

Top left is PF=1 i.e. a pure resistor - the power waveform never goes negative. Top right is for a complex impedance where the current lags by 60 degrees (a resistor in parallel with an inductor would achieve this). Bottom left is purely for an inductor and, as you should be able to see, the power waveform has an average value of zero.

> what would negative power in negative cycle represent?

That represents power being delivered back to the supply.